# how to convert .h263 in avi or any other extension that can be played?c++

Tags: c++, video, h.264, asterisk

I am working with asterisk. I have in the voicemail folder a .h263 file and a .wav file. As I guess the .h263 file contains only the video information and the .wav file contains the audio information. I would like to ask how can I combine the .h263 and .wav and convert than in a .mp3 file for example?
I need this in c++.

Are there any easiest way to do this? I am new to video mail and asterisk. Need some help with the code and way of solving this problem.

I would like to specify that i am working in Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the point of combining the video and audio when MP3 can only contain audio? Just convert the .wav file.

Comment: is there a way i can combine audio and video?

Comment: I've edited my question. I need an avi format. sorry for mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out open-source [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) library. Fist try to sove your task using command-line ffmpeg. Then you can embed this functionality into your app using their `avcodec` and `avformat` libraries.

Comment: are there some online examples with this? Do I have to stream audio and video into a single file and than to use the ffmpeg for encoding into avi?

Comment: @user1222905: check ffmpeg help: `ffmpeg --help`. You can specify two input streams from different files and output to single avi-file, with or without transcoding

Comment: thx for reply. I would like to ask you if i add the ffmpeg command line for convertion in a c++ code that is under a custmer licence ( i mean the application is going to be selled ) is it ok? I mean can I use ffmpeg under these conditions?

Comment: FFMPEG by default is [LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) (seems it's sufficient for you task, FFMPEG has also parts licensed by GPL license). You need to investigate this license to be sure, there're some restrictions. The main one is that you need to use FFMPEG as shared library so user can upgrade it to newer version not touching your propriatery code.

Comment: so it is ok to use it? thx very much for your help. It seems that FFMPEG is the onlyone that converts h263 to avi. I've tried other libraires: menencoder, mplayer with no help

Comment: i can't seem to make it work. I use : ffmpeg -i test.h263 -f avi -vcodec xvid -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 file.avi but i obtain this: [NULL @ 0x9dc3bc0]Format detected only with low score of 24, misdetection possible!
[mp3 @ 0x9dc4dc0]Header missing
    Last message repeated 212 times
[mp3 @ 0x9dc3bc0]Could not find codec parameters (Audio: mp2, 0 channels, s16)
[mp3 @ 0x9dc3bc0]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
 why?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to convert the files, you can execute an `ffmpeg` command from your application, e.g. using `execvp`, for example:

```
ffmpeg -i audio_input.wav -i h263_video output_video.avi
```

For programming solution see [decoding_encoding.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decoding_encoding.c) example.

Comment: what about encoding from h263 to avi?

Comment: If you ask, how to preserve (h263) video encoding when converting to avi, use `-vcodec copy` option.

Comment: Is it recognized by `ffmpeg` at all? Which command did you use?

Comment: i used this command: ffmpeg -i test.h263 -f avi -vcodec xvid -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 file.avi

Comment: You mentioned that audio should come from .wav file. You need to add `-i wave_file` then.